# Movesense firmware update

Tags: android, ios, c

How to update the [movesense](/questions/tagged/movesense) sensor device firmware using the iOS and/or Android library?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

The latest version of Movesense device lib (0.3.0.65) supports DFU (device firmware update) over BLE. To update the firmware you need to have a Movesense device with bootloader and Movesense software with version => 0.3.0.65.

To update the firmware:

1. Build your movesense device app using command "ninja dfupkg". The firwmare update package will be created in build folder with name *movesense_dfu.zip*.
2. Move the firwmare update package to the phone you plan to use (or your Google Drive)
3. Use Movesense Mobile sample app to send *PUT* request to path */Device/System/Mode* with value *12* (= Go to Firmware update mode). The device will reset into DFU mode. DFU mode is recognizable from the constantly lit LED.
4. Start *nRF Connect* or *nRF ToolBox* app on your mobile. After scan the device shows with name "DfuTarg". Connect to it and press "DFU" button in UI.
5. Select the *movesense_dfu.zip* file and press *Update* button in nRF Connect / nrf ToolBox UI. The UI will show the progress and when the process is completed the Movesense sensor will reset to the new software.

**Note: Do not update a software with BLE disabled or you will not be able to update the device except with the programming jig.**

(OLD: At the moment of writing this (2017-02-01) the only way to update the sensor firmware is by our programming jig which is not generally available (due to high cost). We plan to release the firmware that can be updated over the BLE in about a month (see our [Movesense Newsletter #2](http://us14.campaign-archive2.com/?u=f0430f5ed0b2994f9a6ae614f&id=d7e64ff238)) at which point we will also ship the beta sensors themselves to the beta developers.)

*Full disclosure: I work in Movesense team*